# What does M in AdaBoost.M1 and AdaBoost.M2 stand for?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, adaboost

It is obvious that AdaBoost stands for *Adaptive Boosting*, but what does the M1 and M2 signify? I am not able to find its linguistic significance other than its description and algorithmic profile.

Comment: I'm assuming 'M' is *model* as in *Model 1* and *Model 2*; is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "M" stands for "Multi-class" (Hi Ébe!  I'm a little late to the party.), in contrast to binary, i.e., two-class.

For example, Freund and Schapire have "First Multi-class Extension" as the title of Section 5.1 in their original AdaBoost paper (Happy Boosting!  K. Frank) where they present the AdaBoost.M1 algorithm.  That paper is:  Yoav Freund and Robert E. Schapire, "A Decision-Theoretic Generalization of On-Line Learning and an Application to Boosting, "Journal of Computer and System sciences, 55, 119139 (1997).